# Как в OpenGL нарисовать дугу?

Tags: c++, opengl

Как в opengl c++ нарисовать дугу которая начинается с определённой точки и заканчивается определённой точкой Пример - дуги которые между многоугольниками на картинке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Двух точек недостаточно для определения дуги.

Answer (score 2):

1. Текстурой (спрайтом) - негибко в плане четкости при разных разрешениях.
2. Линией (`GL_LINE`) - не все реализации OpenGL корректно поддерживают задание толщины линии и сглаживание краев.
3. Полоской/лентой треугольников - самый муторный и правильный вариант.

Все точки линии вам все равно придется высчитывать самому.